# How I can clipping vertical line in a CardView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I want clipping vertical line view in radius CardView

like this pic:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="40dp">

        <!-- radiused vertical line here -->

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try with `View` within mentioned `width` and `height`

Comment: @Shashanth Can you help me?

Comment: @vimukthi Yes. not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting curved-shaped background resource for the clipping views.

Here is a sample shape file, you need to modify the radius values according to your need.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="#a40404" />
    <corners
        android:topRightRadius="40dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="40dp"/>
</shape>
```

And the main CardView layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

        <View
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/curved_bg" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/curved_bg" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think this is the best way. Thanks

Comment: Welcome mate, happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Bro try this**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="40dp">

        <View
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="#a40404" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="#a40404" />

        <!-- radiused vertical line here -->

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: I got something like this]

Comment: Hi, thanks. I copy your code, but i get different result!! see: https://i.imgur.com/OQ5hrij.png   why?

Comment: Did you used the whole code i given or just only the views?

Comment: Yes I Copy and paste this.

Comment: Now I try it on genymotion emulator, have different on api 4 and 7. see: https://i.imgur.com/eSRu7Iy.png

Comment: It's true. but only on high api android version work. Thanks