# How to make vertical line fit with cardview?

Tags: android, android-cardview

i want to ask help for how to add vertical line in left side of cardview?

Current result

[image: Vertical line move outside card view]

Expected result
[image: Vertical line fit with card view]

This is the code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView         
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cvRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/lightPink"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/spacing_x">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/viewLine"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/coral"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_h"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/viewLine"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_error_rounded" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
            android:id="@+id/groupDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="tvTitle,tvSubTitle" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            style="@style/TextParagraph2.Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_h"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_x"
            android:textColor="@color/darkGreyBlue"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivLogo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Sorry, it’s not you, It’s us." />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSubTitle"
            style="@style/TextParagraph3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small_x"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_x"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_h"
            android:textColor="@color/darkGreyBlue"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivLogo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTitle"
            tools:text="Internal server problem. Please try again later" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Is my code correct, if not please tell me ?

I already try many ways but still not find the match solution, If you know how fix this issue, please comment bellow, thanks

sorry for my bad english

Comment: i thinks i found the solution from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53991918/how-i-can-clipping-vertical-line-in-a-cardview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your code and ran it. You are using AppCompat libraries, I'm not sure if that was the problem but I'm using androidx and it seems to work well. I just added some dummy properties for color and dimensions.

This is my result:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout9"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.maincontent.DummyFragment">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cvRoot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/clContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewLine"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@color/gradientEndNoDarkMode"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/viewLine"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_error_rounded" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
                android:id="@+id/groupDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:constraint_referenced_ids="tvTitle,tvSubTitle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivLogo"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="Sorry, it’s not you, It’s us." />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSubTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivLogo"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTitle"
                tools:text="Internal server problem. Please try again later" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope it helps!